# file name convention to use for blob uploads in azure

Tags: c#, azure, blob

I am using c# code to upload the content to Blob Storage. And my requirement is to upload the files in a given directory.

I am using the file name in blob with all lower case letters. I want to know if its good idea to retain same file name as in directory or should it be all in lower case ?

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question! Please note that blobs stored in blob storage are **case sensitive**. So if you store them in mixed case (e.g. MyImage.png) but access them in say lower or upper case (e.g. myimage.png), you will get 404 error. My recommendation would be to store them in a format in which you will always access them.